# notification message in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, notifications

i want to show notification in my web application like messegers have (gtalk,yahoo,msn) in system tray or bottom right of the screen,(for me bottom right of the page will work fine)

i have found the link but it is for windows http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx

i need to do it in asp.net with c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always look for a jQuery solution for fancy stuff in a Web Application. :)

[jQuery.UI Messenger\Outlook like message notification Widget](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/2008/07/17/jQueryui-Messenger-Outlook-like-message-notification-Widget.aspx)